# Postgres generate user grant statements for all objects

Tags: postgresql

We have a dev Postgres DB that one of the developers has created an application in. Is there an existing query that will pull information from the role_table_grants table and generate all the correct statements to move into production? PGAdmin will create all the generate scripts for certain things but I haven't found a less manual way rather than just writing all the statements by hand based on the role_table_grants table. Not asking anyone to dump time into creating it, just thought I would ask if there are some existing migration scripts out there that would help.

Thanks.

Comment: role_table_grants is just a system table in Postgres. 

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/infoschema-role-table-grants.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dump the schema to a file; use pg_dump or pg_dumpall with the `--schema-only` option.

Then use `grep` to get all the GRANT and REVOKE statements.

On my dev machine, I might do something like this.

```
$ pg_dump -h localhost -p 5435 -U postgres --schema-only sandbox > sandbox.sql
$ grep "^GRANT\|^REVOKE" sandbox.sql 
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
[snip]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [pg_dumpall](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pg-dumpall.html) is what you need. Probably with `--schema-only` option in order to dump just schema, not development data.

If you need to move not all databases, you can use `pg_dumpall --globals-only` to dump roles (which don't belong to any particular database), and then use [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) to dump one certain databases.